# Why can't I get svg animatemotion to use absolute paths

Tags: animation, svg, path, jquery-animate

The [SVG Path documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) states that using uppercase (M, L) letters means the coordinates are absolute.  So in this  path, it goes to absolute coordinates 100,100.

```
  <rect x="200" y="0" width="30" height="15" style="stroke: #ff0000;">
          <animateMotion path="M0,0 L100,100" begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
```

But that does not seem to be true in reality.  [Here is a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dax006/wgvaypya/2/) animating a rectangle.  The starting points are at 200,0.  If it moves to 100,100 then it should move down and left.  It does not.  It moves to the right.  What's going on?

(My goal is to create an animation that moves through a series of absolute coordinates, and depending on user input, dynamically removes a coordinate, without throwing off the subsequent animations.  Hence I need to use absolute coordinates.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like your coordinate system's origin to be set at (0,0) then you should define your `rect` element to be at (0,0), or `x="0" y="0"`. After this, defining `path="M200,0 L100,100"` for your animateMotion will achieve your desired effect.

This is due to the fact that the coordinate system for SVG transforms is centered around the transforming element by default, so the coordinates (0,0) will be at the location where your element is defined. See the Coordinate System Transforms section of http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/ for a write up on this.

Answer (score 0):

[*The effect of a motion path animation is to add a **supplemental** transformation matrix onto the CTM for the referenced object which causes a translation along the x- and y-axes of the current user coordinate system by the computed X and Y values computed over time.*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement)

So if you want the object to go from 0,0 set `x="0"` rather than `x="200"`